# Get Row Number of an Order ID in Gridview using VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I need to display the row number of a specific orderID in a Gridview. I wish to store it as a session variable:

```
session("rownum"0)
```

However being a beginner, I'm getting a little confused with how to check the Guid OrderID against the OrderID in the QueryString. Do I need to change it to a Label? I'm getting the error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Any help appreciated.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSOrders" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT tblOrders.OrderID, tblOrders.stallmessage, tblOrders.price, tblAccounts.city, tblAccounts.postcode, tblAccounts.phoneNumber, tblOrders.orderDate, tblOrders.orderStatus, tblOrders.type, tblOrders.timeFor, tblOrders.paid, tblOrders.tblNo
    FROM tblOrders INNER JOIN
        tblAccounts ON tblOrders.accountID = tblAccounts.AccountID
    WHERE tblOrders.orderStatus='Completed'
        ORDER BY tblOrders.orderDate ASC">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="gdvOrders" width="100%" runat="server"ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No orders" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" DataKeyNames="orderID" DataSourceID="DSOrders" PageSize="20" AllowSorting="True">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
    <Columns>    
        <asp:BoundField DataField="orderID" HeaderText="OrderID" />
.
.
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

VB.NET

```
session("rownum")=0

For Each r As GridViewRow in gdvOrders.Rows
    If r.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then 
        Dim orderID As Label
        orderID = r.Cells(0).FindControl("orderID") 
        If orderID.text = Request.Querystring("orderID")
            session("rownum") = session("rownum") + 1
        End If
    End If
Next r
```

Comment: Can you tell me in which line of this code you get the exception ?

Comment: @Ale865 If orderID.text = Request.Querystring("orderID")

Comment: I guess `orderID` is null, which means that control was not found with `r.Cells(0).FindControl("orderID")`

Comment: @Arsen The gridview shows that there's data in there so I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using TemplateField instead:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gdvOrders" width="100%" runat="server" style="font-size:1.5em" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No orders" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" DataKeyNames="orderID" DataSourceID="DSOrders" PageSize="20" AllowSorting="True">
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
            <Columns>    
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OrderID">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblOrderID" text='<%# Eval("orderID").ToString %>' runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using FindControl you can get control only with `ID` value as mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_Control_FindControl_System_String_):

> Searches the current naming container for a server control with the
> specified id parameter.

So I think you wanted to get row text value, not the control text

```
Dim orderID = r.Cells(0).Text 
If orderID = Request.Querystring("orderID")
    session("rownum") = session("rownum") + 1
```

Comment: could be my fault , but you are assigning a String type value to a Label type object . In his code, orderID is a label .

Comment: @Ale865 Here `orderID` must be `string` type variable, thanks for mentioning that